# Can't figure out what type of argument I'm meant to pass to this sort method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I'm trying to get my program to sort an array using the methods given to us by the textbook but I can't figure out what the parameter wants.

This is the code given to us:

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    final int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j], a[j-1]); j--) {
            exch(a, j, j-1);
        }
        assert isSorted(a, 0, i);
    }
    assert isSorted(a);
}
```

And this is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double power = 0;
    int i;
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (i=8;i<=18;i++){
        power = Math.pow(2, i);
        double[] doubleArray = new double[(int) power];
        for(int j = 0;j<doubleArray.length;j++) doubleArray[j] = rand.nextInt();
        Insertion.sort(doubleArray);
    }
}
```

Here I'm attempting create a main loop that iterates over the lengths that are powers of 2 from 28 to 218. Inside the loop,I randomly generate an array of integers of that length and call the sort on that array.(The sort method is in the class Insertion which is why it says Insertion.sort)

To my understanding the sorting method was made for arrays but the way it's written Eclipse is giving me an error saying that "The method sort(T[]) in the type Insertion is not applicable for the arguments (double[])".

Answer (score 1):

Primitives (`double`) can't used with generics, it's expecting some type of `Object`.  Also `double` is not `Comparable` (it does not implement the required `interface`...because it's a primitive).

You could, instead use `Double`, for example...

```
    for (i = 8; i <= 18; i++) {
        power = Math.pow(2, i);
        Double[] doubleArray = new Double[(int) power];
        for (int j = 0; j < doubleArray.length; j++) {
            doubleArray[j] = (double)rand.nextInt();
        }
        sort(doubleArray);
    }
```

As it's both an `Object` and implements `Comparable`

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer! Looking back it was an obvious mistake but I'm new to Java and the distinction between Double(object) and double(primitive) still gets me now and again. In the future I will try avoiding primitives as they often get me in trouble!

Comment: Nothing wrong with primitives, but with auto-boxing support, its easy to do without

Comment: One more question: why use T? Is it jargon/shorthand for Object? Could I replace T with any variable and it would still ask for an Object type?

Comment: It's a place holder known as a generic type, see [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more details.  But basically it means you don't need to write a method for EVERY object type you expect to have to handle, but can provide a kind of filtering at the same. For example, `<T extends Comparable<T>>` basically means that it handle any object type, which extends from `Comparable`, where `Comparable` can compare with the same type...:P

Comment: Just remember, "generics are fun" ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<T extends Comparable<T>>` simply means that T has to be of type Comparable at least. However, Comparable is also Generic, so you have to specify the type of Comparable as well, which is with the type T.

Classes of collections, and **wrapper classes** for primitive types satisfy this condition, so you can use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array Objects, where the objects are of the same type and implement the Comparable interface to themselves.

The primitive double does not implement Comparable. But Double does. 
[Double implements `Comparable<Double>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can not use array of primitive type as argument for `sort(T[])` because primitives do not implement `Comparable`. Use wrapper types for primitives like `Double`, `Integer`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  double power = 0;
  int i;
  Random rand = new Random();
  for (i=8;i<=18;i++){
    power = Math.pow(2, i);
    Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[(int) power];
    for(int j = 0;j<integerArray.length;j++) integerArray[j] = rand.nextInt();
    Insertion.sort(integerArray);
  }
}
```